# Display servlet response message without navigating away from JSP page after Jersey multipart upload

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload, jersey

I have an HTML web page running on Tomcat with a Jersey multipart file upload service.

My code is based on a tutorial's example. This is the file upload HTML form:

```
<form action="../services/upload/csv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <p>
    <input type="file" name="file" size="45" accept=".csv"/>
   </p>

   <input type="submit" value="Upload"  class="file-upload-button" />
</form>
```

The Java backend code in the tutorial's example had the following return value:

```
 return Response.ok("Data uploaded successfully!!").build();
```

This takes the user to a blank page with only the message ("Data uploaded successfully!!").

I found that instead of the message I could also put a URL there or reload the same page by putting the URL of the current page. However, none of these are desirable. I don't want to navigate anywhere just because a file was uploaded. I just want a message to appear that says "file uploaded successfully" on the same page.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can also use jQuery form js to upload this form regardless of what ever technology you are using it will serve just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Completely possible, though you'd probably need to use javascript for most solutions.

Use ajax to upload the file and check what the response is, and in js if the response indicates a success you can edit the html on the page or send an alert to let them know it's been done successfully

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if the question is unclear; I'm using Jersey multipart for the file upload. That part can't change.

Comment: Yeah, your BACKEND is using that to receive the file, but the posting to that form could be done from js. (Dropzone, for example)